# How can we ignore metadata (SVN properties changes) diff while creating/applying patch in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn

I am creating a patch for one of my project in eclipse. I am having eclipse Kepler Release and having installed Subversion client kit(1.7.9.2). After creating patch, I have realized that in patch file, its putting following content related to properties changes.

```
Property changes on: ao/search_indexes.py
___________________________________________________________________
Added: svn:executable
## -0,0 +1 ##
+*
```

This is creating  a problem when one of my other team member is trying to apply this patch in his environment. He is also having same eclipse and subversion installed on his machine.

Is there a way to tell eclipse to compare only the actual content and ignore any SVN properties related data while applying patch or is there any way to create patch ignoring this SVN properties related changes?

Answer (score 1):

You can manually edit the patch file to remove those lines. The format is pretty easy to follow, it's hard to mess it up, and there is nothing in that patch that will be messed up by removing parts of it. Just be sure to remove entire "hunks" and you'll be fine.

When I make multiple unrelated changes affecting the same set of files, I often create patches with all these unrelated changes mixed together, so I can revert my working copy, split the single patch into multiple, and apply them one by one to commit only one set of related changes at a time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I have edited my patch file and removed the unrelated content. But I just want to know if there is way to just ignore those changes while  creating/applying patch. Any thoughts ?